# nbtstat in c++ not running

Tags: windows, visual-c++, windows-server-2008, popen

In my visual c++ code;
with _popen() or system(), I ran 'nbtstat', it runs perfectly in win7 but when I run my executable in windows server 2008, it says:

'nbtstat' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

(I have nbtstat in my windows server 2008, I can run it from cmd or run.)

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsserver2008r2networking/thread/0cbfaf51-8fa5-46b1-afb4-e87bceca82f7/

In this article it is explained that windows auto-redirects you to SysWOW64 but nbtstat is in system32 so using "Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection" I solved my problem.

Good day to you.